# Regular expression for lines starts with capital letter word

Tags: java, regex

I have below lines of text in my text file,

```
James is working in London
this is a program developed in java
Program is working
```

I want to get the lines which have starting word with capital letter

```
James is working in London
Program is working
```

Thanks

Comment: line.matches("^\\p{Lu}.*$"), still +1 for Jack, you can google stuff like that petty easily.

Answer (score 8):

For English language, you can use this

```
^[A-Z].*
```

The ^ is for start of line. and [A-Z] means any capital letter.

Comment: Note that you can also use `\p{Upper}` for uppercase letters.

Answer (score 6):

More faster if you use:

```
if (Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: I didn't see this answer when I posted mine; +1