# Django path converter not converting value in path

Tags: python, django, regex, url, path-converters

I have an app that should be able to take a field's value in lower and uppercase.

The url below should work `http://localhost:8000/app/family=Araceae/` but fail if value is `araceae`.

I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) but it's not working.

```
path('app/family=<str:family>/', views.SpeciesDetail_family.as_view(), name='family')
```

I made a converter to convert the value to lower case if it's in uppercase but is returning 404 saying URL does not match the patterns below

```
admin/
app/family=<value:family>/ [name='family']
app/family=<value:family><drf_format_suffix:format> [name='family']

The current path, app/family=araceae/, didn’t match any of these.
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from app import converters, views

register_converter(converters.convert_value_to_lowercase, 'value')

urlpatterns = [path('app/family=<value:family>/', views.SpeciesDetail_family.as_view(), name='family')]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

**converters.py**

```
class convert_value_to_lowercase:
    regex = '[A-Z]'
    
    def to_python(self, value):
        value = value.lower()
        return value

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for lines starts with capital letter word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106596/regular-expression-for-lines-starts-with-capital-letter-word) Tl;DR The regex: `[A-Z]` matches just **one** uppercase character and nothing else.

Comment: No, changing regex to `'^[A-Z].*'` does not work. The problem is that the path does not match the pattern where it should be.

Comment: `^` in a regular expression means the string should start at that point, given your url has a prefix you shouldn't really add that there... `[A-Z].*` or `[A-Z][^/]*` is probably what you really want.

Comment: You're right! I just understood that the regex will check the entire URL and not just the value so `[A-Za-z][^/]*` works. Next step is to figure out how to make the queryset filter also case insensitive.